# Java writing a file as pure "windows-1252"

Tags: java, encoding

I have got the following Array of decimal ascii values

```
int[] istr={146,192,128,224,185,152,240,192,6,26,66,72,186,184,88,128,182,40,104,96,36,236,152,128,212,200,64,64,101,252,174,0,96,192,112,24,173,228,200,0,192,128,96,192,144,116,201,48};
```

I want to write those values into a file as (ascii / windows-1252) characters.

```
HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:    ’À€à¹˜ðÀBHº¸X€¶(h`$ì˜€ÔÈ@@eü®
MY OUTPUT:                  ?À?à¹?ðÀBHº¸X?¶(h`$ì??ÔÈ@@eü®
```

As you can easily see there are some chars in my output that will not appear in the file as I would expect them to do.
The code that writes my file:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output),"windows-1252");
    try {
        for (int c : istr) {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

So why are some special characters not correctly written to my file?

Comment: How are you looking at the file afterwards? Note that anything about 127 is *not* a "decimal ascii value".

Comment: With Notepad++ (Encoding set to ANSI for both files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`Writer.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28int%29) you're meant to provide a Unicode value.

So looking at your first character for example, you've got Unicode 146, aka U+0092. Looking at the [Unicode chart for U+0080 to U+00FF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf), that's the "private use 2" character. It's not clear why you'd expect it to come out as an apostrophe.

If you've got the exact bytes that you want to end up in the file, you shouldn't use a `Writer` at all - you should just use an `OutputStream`.

Comment: The "correct output" is produced by exact the same programme written in Delphi (old version which doesn't support unicode). I'am trying to rewrite this in Java. According to ASCII tables (http://www.jelks.nu/XML/ASCIIchart.html) 146 should end up as an apostrophe.

Comment: @k_wave: I don't think you've read my answer carefully enough. When you call `out.write(146)`, what *character* do you expect that to write, and why? The input to the method is meant to be the Unicode value of a character. That character is "private use 2" *not* an apostrophe.

Comment: @k_wave: The page you referred to even states this: "Characters 128 to 159 are Unicode control characters."

Comment: Jep those are unicode chars - I know. So the question is why am I able to print an apostrophe in Delphi/C/C++ by converting 146 to char?

Comment: However, using the outputstream directly did the job.

Comment: @k_wave: *All* characters in Java are you Unicode characters. Your Delphi/C/C++ code probably isn't trying to do *any* interpretation of the data - it's just dumping it directly to the file, just like `OutputStream` does.

Answer (score -2):

outputstream is abstract class. how is the write function then used? 
I am having similar trouble while writing chinese characters to an excel file . i built my code in a very similar way to code mentioned. and intead of OutputStreamWriter 
=new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output),"utf-8");
 i  used 
=new OutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output),"utf=8");

i was able to built the code with this modification but the the value in excel is still gibberish

Comment: just use `new FileOutputStream()`. FileOutputstream inherits from Outputstream. -1 for posting this as answer and not as comment.